# Is Akuma Ryu's father?

Tags: street-fighter

A friend of mine said that Street Fighter was "martial arts Star Wars." I asked him his reasoning.

He said "Ryu was abandoned to Goken in order to be trained in a noble art, Akuma returned to kill Goken because he was the only one to have ever defeated him, and Ryu swears to defeat a man who is, unbeknownst to him, his father."

All that did make sense in his Star Wars argument except the blood relations between our hero and villain.

Can anyone verify this?

Comment: From everything I can find, it seems this theory is based on a comment made in the movie *Street Fighter Alpha: Generations* which is considered non-canon.

Comment: How come you didn't put it as an answer?

Comment: My only sources are unsourced wikis and message board comments. I'd prefer to find something a bit more concrete.